# Changing mail attributes of a AD user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I would like your assistance, I'm facing an issue when trying to change email attributes via AD PowerShell for users. My problem occurs when I attempt to configure the PrimarySMTPAddress, it is removing all secondary emails. I need to be able to change the SMTP address without removing the existing values.

I tried this one but it didn't work, it replace everything on the proxyaddress for the SMTP.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity "SamAccountName" -server domain -UserPrincipalName "newsmtp@domain.com" -Replace @{proxyAddresses="SMTP:newsmtp@domain.com";mail="newsmtp@domain.com"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Changing the e-mail address of a account via ad attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`proxyAddresses` is a collection attribute, you need to use `-Add` instead of `-Replace` if you want to *add* a new value to it:

```bash
$setADUserSplat = @{
    Identity          = 'SamAccountName'
    server            = 'domain'
    UserPrincipalName = 'newsmtp@domain.com'
    EmailAddress      = 'newsmtp@domain.com'
    Add               = @{
        proxyAddresses = 'SMTP:newsmtp@domain.com'
    }
}

Set-ADUser @setADUserSplat
```